# Updating information by ID in a database - ASP.NET/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database

Thanks for looking at my question in advanced.

I am trying to update information in a database from a save button.

At the moment I have got it saving, but it saves the update as a new row.

I have got the ID of the row that I wish to change but I am struggling to get it to work.

ASP.NET:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSave" CssClass="btnSubmit" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
```

C#:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int ItemID = 0;
    var Item = Placements.GetPlacementByExpiry(ItemID, false);
    if (Item == null)
    {
        Item = new Placements();
    }

    Item.CategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCategory.SelectedValue);
    Item.Title = txtTitle.Text;
    Item.Company = txtCompany.Text;
    Item.Location = txtLocation.Text;
    Item.Duration = txtDuration.Text;
    Item.SalaryFrom = Convert.ToDecimal(txtSalaryFrom.Text);
    Item.SalaryTo = Convert.ToDecimal(txtSalaryTo.Text);
    Item.SalaryType = ddlSalaryType.Text;
    Item.Description = txtDescription.Text;
    Item.Responsibilities = txtResponsibilities.Text;
    Item.Requirements = txtRequirements.Text;
    DateTime ExpiryDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtExpiryDate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    Item.ExpiryDate = ExpiryDate;
    Item.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;

    if (Item.ID == 0)
    {
        Placements.CreatePlacement(Item);
    }
    else
    {
        Placements.UpdatePlacement(Item);
    }

    mvEdit.SetActiveView(vwList);
}
```

I have tried putting a command argument on the button and changed it in the back end, but receive the following error:

```
Error   1   No overload for 'btnSave_Click' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'  C:\Users\laura\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\ThirdYearProject\tools\controls\placements\edit.ascx   239
```

I've been trying to fix it for a while now but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you get an existing ITEM from Placements.GetPlacementByExpiry(ItemID, false);, instead of new an ITEM, you can add break point see if it is a new ITEM. Or, output your ITEM information and check before it writes to database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Item.ID == 0 is not 0 either null or some other values. Please check the value of that.

Comment: Sorry, I probably should have added that I have this in the function executed before (btnSave.CommandArgument = PlacementID.ToString();) but I don't know how to get that information to the function I have written above?

Comment: int PlacementID = Convert.ToInt32(btnSave.CommandArgument); instead of 0 works. Not sure why I did that to be honest!

Comment: Please int.tryparse instead of converting. Tryparse won't throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a typo? Shouldn't this line

```
btnSave_Click+= new System.EventHandler(this.btnSave_Click);
```

be moved to the possibly the Page_Load event or even the Pre_Init?

And I think below answer should be help to you

[Sample program Event bubbling in Asp.Net](http://forums.asp.net/t/1285712.aspx)